# Disable the creation of new fields with update_many method

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am using the PyMongo driver and I have a problem with the `update_many` method.

If I try to update the value of a non-existing field on a document, this field will be created. I would like the method to raise an error instead.

As I am developing my own library, I can write code dedicated to this problem. Therefore I am interested in all the solutions you can provide to me.

Comment: How about update only if the field exists?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. How could I know if the field exists ?

Comment: So you want to update only if the field  [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) Right?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is update only the documents that contain the given field.

To do this, you need to use the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator in your filter criteria to select only those documents.

```
db.collection.update_many({'fiedname': {'$exists': True}}, update_document)
```

If you want raise an exception when no document matches your query criteria, the best way to do this is to check the value of [`modified_count`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult.modified_count) or [`matched_count`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult.matched_count) after your query. If it is equals to 0 then you raise your exception.

Everything put together:

```
update_result = db.collection.update_many({'fiedname': {'$exists': True}}, update_document)
if update_result.modified_count == 0: # you can also use matched_count
    # raise your exception or what do whatever you want here.
```

Comment: Yes that is it. One more thing, how should I do if I want to raise an error if a not existing field is used ?

Comment: Why do you need to raise an exception? If the field does not exist, the document will not be updated.

Comment: because I write a library for users who want to have feedbacks on their actions. I may have a solution:
first do a find query with only `{'fiedname': {'$exists': True}}` as a filter. I cursor.count() is 0 then the field is unknown and I can raise an exception.

Comment: @MatiasDurruty that will be expensive. I've updated my answer

Comment: When I use update_many I already have a filter like {'aField':aValue}, so if no documents are modified it could also be because no documents have the value aValue for aField. Therefore I think I must first make a find query with only $exists.